# vue.js pinia store typescript migration

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

I try to migrate to Typescript pinia store. At `getters` section I cant use store as parameter of actions. If gave an interface ITestStore to `store` [image: My Error]

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

interface ITestStore {
    name: string | null
    getName: (val: ITestStore) => string | null
    setName: () => void
}

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('test', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            name: '',
        }
    },

    actions: {
        setName() {
            this.name = "Test"
        },
    },

    getters: {
        /* !!!!!! hear is it !!!!!! */
        getName: (state :any) :string | null => { 
            if (!state.name) {
                state.setName()
            }
            return state.name
        },
    },
})
```